# UnityConfiguration Scanning

Tags: configuration, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm using the Microsoft Unity 2.1 IoC container. This doesn't feature automatic / convention-based configuration like Windsor or StructureMap, so I've downloaded UnityConfiguration 1.4.1 (see http://thedersen.com/projects/unityconfiguration/) via NuGet.

Configuration is performed by creating UnityRegistries (like Installers and Modules in other containers). I've created a couple of these for registering different types of classes:

```
internal class WidgetRegistry : UnityRegistry
{
    public WidgetRegistry()
    {
        Register<IWidget, Widget>();
    }
}

internal class GubbinsRegistry : UnityRegistry
{
    public GubbinsRegistry()
    {
        Register<IGubbins, FirstGubbins>().WithName("gubbins1");
        Register<IGubbins, SecondGubbins>().WithName("gubbins2");
    }
}
```

In the composition root, I can add the following:

```
container.Configure(
    unityRegistry =>
        {
            unityRegistry.AddRegistry<WidgetRegistry>();
            unityRegistry.AddRegistry<GubbinsRegistry>();
        });
```

...and everything works properly. But this means manually modifying the composition root code every time I add a new registry. What I'd like to do is use the scanning facilities of UnityConfiguration to do this automatically for me; that is, remove the above calls to AddRegistry() and replace them with something like this:

```
container.Configure(
    unityRegistry =>
    {
        unityRegistry.Scan(
            scanner =>
            {
                scanner.AssembliesInBaseDirectory();
                scanner.ForRegistries();
            });
    });
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work at all. The WidgetRegistry and GubbinsRegistry constructors are never invoked.

I suspect I'm not using this feature of UnityConfiguration correctly. Does anyone have any ideas how to do this?

Many thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your registries from internal to public.

Comment: D'Oh! The painfully obvious didn't even occur to me. That worked perfectly.

Many thanks for your help, and kudos for writing a GREAT library.